# Issue with weighted table function in R

Tags: r, weighted

I have a the following dataset (example)

```
head(LK)

      Weight question result
15 0.9633132       x1    Yes
16 1.0327943       x1    Yes
19 1.0002033       x1    Yes
20 0.9438802       x1    Yes
24 0.8067644       x1     No
49 0.8951687       x1     No
```

When I use the wtd.table function for a one-way table it works well

```
wtd.table(LK$result, weights=LK$Weight)

$x
[1] "No"  "Yes"

$sum.of.weights
[1]  747.2105 1996.9381
```

However, when i try and use this for a two-way table - i get this error:

```
wtd.table(LK$result, LK$question, weights=LK$Weight)

Error in match.arg(type) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector
```

I have seen examples of two-way weighted tables that use this syntax so not sure what the issue is. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Which package is `wtd.table` function from?

Comment: "survey" i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just interested in the sum of weights and counts, but do not need the results as a "table", you can try this

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- tribble(
  ~Weight, ~question, ~result,
  0.9633132,       "x1",    "Yes",
  1.0327943,       "x1",    "Yes",
  1.0002033,       "x1",    "Yes",
  0.9438802,       "x1",    "Yes",
  0.8067644,       "x1",     "No",
  0.8951687,       "x1",     "No"
)
data
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   Weight question result
#>    <dbl> <chr>    <chr> 
#> 1  0.963 x1       Yes   
#> 2  1.03  x1       Yes   
#> 3  1.00  x1       Yes   
#> 4  0.944 x1       Yes   
#> 5  0.807 x1       No    
#> 6  0.895 x1       No


data %>% 
  group_by(question, result) %>% 
  summarise(n = n(), weight = sum(Weight))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'question'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#> # Groups:   question [1]
#>   question result     n weight
#>   <chr>    <chr>  <int>  <dbl>
#> 1 x1       No         2   1.70
#> 2 x1       Yes        4   3.94
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>